# Multiplas expressões regulares em uma string com barras

Tags: php, regex

Eu preciso de uma expressão regular que combine com o final de uma URL no seguinte formato:

```
/somente-letras/somente-numeros[/]
```

Para combinar a parte de `somente-letras`, eu usei `~^/[A-Z]+$~`, porém a partir do momento que coloco uma barra, daí nada mais funciona.

Os testes que eu fiz:

```
URL: /testando-minha-url
REGEX: ~^/[a-z-]+$~
SAÍDA: true
```

Colocando uma barra no final da URL

```
URL: /testando-minha-url/
REGEX: ~^/[a-z-]+$~
SAÍDA: false
```

Colocando uma barra na expressão

```
URL: /testando-minha-url/
REGEX: ~^/[a-z-]/+$~
SAÍDA: false
```

Ou seja, meu problema está a partir da barra (forward slash).

Depois depois da barra, eu preciso que combine (match) somente números, e possivelmente a que barra final seja opcional, funcione com ou sem ela.

Estou usando a função `preg_math` do PHP, `preg_match($regex, $str)`

É possível? Onde estou errando?

Comment: Tens de "escapar" essa barra com "\", e na verdade o `-` também... Já [testaste `^\/[a-z\-]\/`](https://regex101.com/r/pK6jU3/1)?

Comment: Eu não havia escapado pois estou usando `~` como delimitador, porém tentei o que sugeriu, também não funcionou, também tentei dessa forma `/^\/[a-z\-]\/+$/` porém não obtive resultados.

Comment: `/+$~` diz que sua string deve terminar com uma barra.

Comment: A regex: `^\/[(a-z\-)]+\/[(0-9)]+$` deu certo para a seguinte string no formato `/testando-minha-string/2785`,  agora como eu faço para a ultima barra possa ser opcional? @Sergio esse site é milagroso, me ajudou muito a chegar nesse resultado.

Comment: @Sergio não a necessidade de escapar o `-` caso ele seja o ultimo elemento do `[]` :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert verdade, mas é bom referir para quem não souber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A seguinte expressão resolve meu problema: `^\/[a-z\-]+\/[0-9]+\/?+$`

Encontrei a solução utilizando [este site](https://regex101.com/) que foi sugerido através do [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) em conjunto com um pequeno aprendizado no site [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/)

Salvei a solução no link que pode ser testado: https://regex101.com/r/fC0gF4/1

Comment: Acho que da pra simplicar a regex assim `#^/([\w-]+)(/\d+)?$#`

Comment: Obrigado @rray vou testar, não entendo muito bem de regex. No meu projeto eu dei uma leve simplificada usando outro delimitador, `~^/[(a-zA-Z0-9-)]+/[(0-9)]+/?+$~`

Comment: Pode tornar a expressão a case insensitive, com o modificador `i` do [PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) é só colocar ele após o delimitador, `~i`, já simplifica mais um poquinho :D

Comment: se você não tiver problema com o  `_` pode alterar para `~^/[\w-]+/\d+/?+$~`

Comment: Obs.: como você pode ver no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uD0aM0/2), grupos não funcionam dentro de `[]`, então ao fazer `[(0-9)]` você esta dizendo que aceita também os `()` parenteses.

Comment: Obrigado, eu esqueci de atualizar o link.

Comment: `\w` também casa números, então não é uma boa quando se quer só letras. Pode-se fazer uma "dupla negação", tipo `[^\W\d_]`, mas não só fica difícil de ler quanto no caso não dá pra combinar com `-`, então na minha opinião a forma explícita é melhor mesmo (tal como está na resposta). P.S. O que você quer dizer com `?+` no final? Eu conheço `+?`, mas não sei o que essa combinação faz. Não seria só `?`?

Comment: Esquece, já descobri [o que o `?+` faz](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Answer (score 3):

Seu erro foi colocar o `+` no lugar errado:

```
URL: /testando-minha-url/
REGEX: ~^/[a-z-]/+$~
SAÍDA: false
```

Isso está dizendo pra casar uma barra, depois *um único caractere* que seja letras ou traço, seguido de uma ou mais barras. Colocando o `+` no lugar certo deve resolver seu problema:

```
URL: /testando-minha-url/
REGEX: ~^/[a-z-]+/$~
```

Isso casa uma barra, seguida de um ou mais caracteres que sejam letras ou traço, seguido de uma barra no final.

A partir daí é só fazer a mesma coisa pros números, colocando um `?` na última barra pra ela ser opcional ([como você já descobriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104292/215)):

```
~^/[a-z-]+/\d+/?$~
```

Comment: E a parte para capturar os números no final, caso existirem?

Comment: @rray Eu estava somente comentando sobre a tentativa de solução do AP, já que ninguém havia apontado isso. Não achei necessário ir até o final, já que ele já tinha encontrado uma resposta. Mas posso completar, se acha importante.

Comment: A não, sem problema, não foi p pentelhar sua resposta, fiquei curioso de saber se tinha uma regex alternativa.

Comment: @rray hehe não, nesse caso não vejo muita margem pra melhoria (pois os caracteres são mutuamente exclusivos), a solução do AP é satisfatória.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @mgibsonbr, essas regex ainda me dão muita dor de cabeça quando preciso usa-las, preciso treinar ou encontrar alguma referência boa.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri Você conhece o site [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (em inglês)? É a principal referência que eu uso, explica cada detalhe das regexes por mais obscuro que seja, e ainda compara sua implementação em diferentes linguagens e plataformas.